# Limit on number of files in gvim

Tags: linux, vim, tabs

Is there a limit on number of files gvim can open. I have list of 1500 files in "filelist" and I use

cat filelist | xargs gvim

But I have 1300 files open in one gvim and 200 files in another gvim. I could not find anything in my vimrc which could limit the number of files .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you rather hit the command line `xargs` limit - see [here](http://offbytwo.com/2011/06/26/things-you-didnt-know-about-xargs.html), the **Maximum command length** section.

You can test by using `xargs` with a small `-s` value - if it opens even more `gvim` instances, that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did not know about ARG_MAX before. On checking, getconf ARG_MAX, I have a high value of 2621440. But I am able to open only ~1270 files in single gvim instance.

Comment: @Raghav - Even better test by using `<filelist xargs sh -c 'echo $#' :` - this prints the number of arguments passed to each invocation of the command.  By the way: How long are the names in `filelist`?